# Riccati equation: Do there exist any alternative solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a Riccati equation in the form:

$\phi_{\xi}=\,\,r+p\,\phi+q\, \phi^{2}$

through use of transformation $\phi=\,\frac{1}{2}V-\frac{p}{2q}$ this change to standard form as:

$V_{\xi}=V^{2}+\frac{4rq-p^{2}}{4}$

for $V=\,\frac{\psi_{\xi}}{\psi}$  the  Ricaati equation further simplifies to

$\psi_{\xi\xi}-\frac{4rq-p^{2}}{4}\,\psi=\,0$

which is second order linear differential equation that can be easily solved.

So my question, is there any other possible procedure to solve Riccati equation because the assumption $V=\,\frac{\psi_{\xi}}{\psi}$ is imposing restriction on general solution ??

Comment: Why do you think that $V=\frac{\psi_\zeta}{\psi}$ is imposing restriction on general solution ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: By restriction I mean type of solution that we obtain in this way, since $V$ is rational function whose numerator is derivative of denominator, though this help in simplification.

Comment: Can you prove that any function cannot be written on the form of a rational function whose numerator is derivative of denominator ? If you cannot prove it, there is no restriction at all. Again give an example where a restriction is is observed.

Comment: @JJacquelin.....You seems to be proving me wrong by contradiction and surely I am wrong, but I am asking about possibility of another solution which I could have been unaware of. If I could find that function then this question could have been already answered. The point is, in this way the solution of Riccati equation seems restrictive.